# Grails 3.1.1 Many to Many Hibernate Mapping Exception foreign key columns

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have two domain classes that look like this:

```
class Project {
    String name
    User creator
    static hasMany = [contributors: User]
    static constraints = {
    }
}

class User {
  String name
  static hasMany = [projects: Project]
  static belongsTo = Project
  static constraints = {
  }
}
```

When I start the grails 3.1.1 simple application, it gives me a hibernate Exception:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key
>   (FK_8drt7f0i3uc82gocadmc6v8t8:project_contributors [])) must have same
>   number of columns as the referenced primary key (project [id]).

I noticed that if I remove User creator line from Project, it works, but I need to keep track of Project creators. Can someone please throw some light on how I can make it work?

Comment: I ran it with grails 3.0.11. It works properly

Comment: Actually I came across this problem when I tried to migrate my application from grails 3.0.x to 3.1.1. It was working in 3.0.x. You might want to try it in grails 3.1.1